# Assistance with form and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I will like an assistance with the following.

I have three input the first one is Identity number , second one is Date of birth and the third one is gender. What I want is when I insert an Identity number on the first field to automatic insert dateofbirth and gender. South African ID numbers contain date of birth and gender. All I want is when I insert  ID number, Birthdate and gender to automatic insert

Sample of identity number is `140101 5000 089` - The first six number is date of birth start with yymmdd and the second number is if a number start with 0-4 its a female and if its start with 5-9 its a male

```
First name: <input type="number" name="id_number" maxlength="13"><br>
Birthdate: <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="birthdate"><br>
Gender: <input type="text" name="gender"><br>
```

Comment: whats the question? can you post your code. Also, so many tags with no justification

Comment: Time to learn about substr or regular expressions.

Comment: You need to split your identity number and then interpret the tokens obtained, for more help see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove "type=number" from your first input. Otherwise it won't allow to type in spaces. Then you can split the ID into an array of words and use them.

```js
var $input1 = $("input[name=id_number]"),
    $input2 = $("input[name=birthdate]"),
    $input3 = $("input[name=gender]");

$input1.on("keyup", function(){
  
 var id = $input1.val().split(" "),
        birthdate="",
        gender="",
        part1 = id[0],
        part2 = id[1];
    
    if(part1.length>5) birthdate = part1.substr(0,2) + "/" + part1.substr(2,2) + "/" + part1.substr(4,2);
 
 $input2.val(birthdate);
    
    if(part2 && part2.length){
         if(parseInt(part2[0]) <5)
             gender = "Female"
         else
             gender = "Male"
      
        $input3.val(gender);
    }
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Identity number : <input type="text" name="id_number" maxlength="13"><br>
Birthdate: <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="birthdate"><br>
Gender: <input type="text" name="gender"><br>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/as6rdtb1/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Uh, hello? OP are you gone? Did you solve your issue? Did it help?

Comment: he posted a message for you  under my answer..pls see below.

Answer (score 0):

First retrive the number from the form (I have modified html a bit)

```
<input type="text" name="id_number" id="IdentityNumber" maxlength="13">

string identityNumber = document.getElementById("IdentityNumber");
```

then you can reuse the logic as used in the answer below for extracting the fields from it..
 (date of birth and gender)

[South African ID Number Validate and Get Age and Gender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344294/south-african-id-number-validate-and-get-age-and-gender)

Then assign them back to the respective textboxes.
(as per the @Elgringorrible answer above.)

Comment: @Elgringorrible  thank you very much , I am still learning coding its my 5 month now. The gender Gender: <input type="text" name="gender"><br> doesn't work I don't know where am I doing wrong